# StackOverflow Error when running

Tags: java, stack-overflow

My code compiles but when I run it, a weird error message pops up.

The error message says

> "java.lang.StackOverflowError:null(in sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig).

What it's supposed to do is print out a panel with a 4x10 of a button array with a button to list all stored info so far. The buttons don't do anything right now but  that's fine because I only care about the actual graphic for now. There is also another class that goes with this for the array list that I can put in the comments if needed.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class CulminatingProjectGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private static JButton[][] jbtNumButtons = new JButton[10][4];
    private static JButton jbtList = new JButton("List");
    ArrayList<Culminating> seats = new ArrayList<Culminating>();
    public CulminatingProjectGUI()
    {
    //Construct JFame object as a container for other objects
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fly By Buddies");
    //Set the dimensions of the window
    frame.setSize(750, 720);
    //Creates a pane for content
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 4));


    jbtList.addActionListener(new CulminatingProjectGUI());
    for (int m = 1,n = 1; n < 11;)
    {

        jbtNumButtons[n][m].addActionListener(new CulminatingProjectGUI());
        if(n == 1)
        {
            jbtNumButtons[n][m].setText(m + "A");
        }
        else if(n == 2)
        {
            jbtNumButtons[n][m].setText(m + "B");
        }
        else if(n == 3)
        {
            jbtNumButtons[n][m].setText(m + "C");
        }
        else if(n == 4)
        {
            jbtNumButtons[n][m].setText(m + "D");
        }
        pane.add(jbtNumButtons[n][m]);
        m++;

        if(m > 4)
        {
            n++;
            m = 0;
        }
    }
    //add content pane to a frame
    pane.add(jbtList);
    frame.setContentPane(pane);


    //Display the frame - window
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //Bring the window to front
    frame.toFront();


    }
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        CulminatingProjectGUI frame = new CulminatingProjectGUI();
        //Create seat array. Still testing.
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("List"))
        {
            String listedFlyers = "";
            for (int h =0;h< 40;h++)
            {
                 listedFlyers = listedFlyers + seats.get(h).toString() + "\n";
            }

            JTextArea text = new JTextArea(listedFlyers, 10, 40);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
        }

        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(""))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the entire error message?

Comment: Yes that's the entire error message

Answer (score 1):

> jbtNumButtons[n][m].addActionListener(new CulminatingProjectGUI());

Here is the problem. You create the new instance of `CulminatingProjectGUI`, and in constructor you create it again and again. You should consider the following:

`jbtNumButtons[n][m].addActionListener(this);`

Comment: Also, the line before the for loop needs the same modification.

Comment: But now the error java.lang.NullPointerException: null pops up

Comment: Show your NPE stack trace please (use pastebin.com or smth)